# Redirecting alias domains to primary domain in IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, rewrite

My hosting setup is Windows 2003 Server with IIS 6.0

I have 3 domains

- ex.com
- ex.org
- ex.net

I want when user open `http://www.ex.com` then they will be redirected to `http://ex.com` and when they open `http://ex.org` or `http://ex.net` then redirect them to `http://ex.com`.

How is it possible in IIS server.

Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the home directory tab of iis web site there is the option "redirect to a url" enter there "http://ex.com" and choose:"a permanent redirection for this resource".

You will have to create a web site for each web site you want to redirect to ex.com . Do it with different IP or host headers.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/fbcccfce-6695-4f92-bd55-869d85ff49fb.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a redirection? Because you can use Host Headers, it's like Apache ServerAlias.

You only have to create one web site, use ex.com as your primary host header, and then add other host headers.

Click right button under your website name and choose "Properties", go to Web Site -> Advanced Button, on "Multiple identities for this web site" press Add, then type the domain name

Example: (All Unassigned, TCP Port 80, ex.net)

Comment: Ohk, let me check it again! Thank!